# Group By and To Dictionary in EF Core 3.1

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

We have updated a service from .Net Core 2.1 to 3.1, while reevaluating queries that broke or became slower during the transition, we came across this query:

```
_context.InboundRecords.GroupBy(x => x.State.ToString()).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count())
```

To make this "work" with the 3.1 breaking changes, we add a to list between the DBSet and the Group By

```
_context.InboundRecords.ToList().GroupBy(x => x.State.ToString()).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count())
```

The issue here is that this brings the entirety of the InboundRecords db set into memory before doing the grouping.  This is identical to the way 2.1 worked, but there has to be a better way of doing this.  Can we tweak this query to only bring back the state and the count of records in that state?

Comment: I would hope (speculate) that `AsEnumerable` is preferable to `ToList` when you must switch to client side evaluation early. It is possible this will be improved in new versions of EF Core as they have agreed to look at improving `GroupBy` translation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can we tweak this query to only bring back the state and the count of records in that state?

Sure we can, by (1) using server side `GroupBy` with intermediate projection containing only keys / aggregates, then (2) convert it client side to the desired shape:

```
_context.InboundRecords
    .GroupBy(x => x.State.ToString())
    .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() }) // (1)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => Count); // (2)
```

Comment: I had to tweak this slightly to _context.InboundRecords.GroupBy(x => x.State).Select(x => new { x.Key, RowCount = x.Count() }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key.ToString(), x => x.RowCount)    It still seems a little slow, but much better.  The issue is State is an enum, so it didn't like tostring ing it early

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Makes sense. But fundamentally that doesn't change the aforementioned principle.

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing with you, I appreciate the explanation

Comment: I have been trying to solve this for a LONG TIME.  This needs more upvotes!